# XCode: Tab Bar Item image is pixelated

Tags: xcode, uitabbaritem

I am using custom images for tab bar icons and they are showing up pixelated and I can't figure out why. The image is 32x32 and 300ppi. I've tried it on 72 and 150ppi and they are all pixelated. Anyone have a solution?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: When I do that, it shows a clipped version of the image.

Comment: I'm running the app on my iPhone4s if that helps.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, is the @2x version of my image (32x32, 300ppi) 64x64, 300ppi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two images one 32 x 32 pixels and named MyIcon.png and one 64 x 64 pixels named MyIcon@2x.png. You then specify MyIcon in the storyboard and iOS will load the correct image for the current hardware.

The ppi (is a print production concept) has no effect in iOS. iOS measures every thing in Points, the iPhone 5 screen is 320 points x 568 points. Retina screens are 2 pixels x 2 pixels for each point. Non retina screens are 1 pixel = 1 point.

UPDATE:
For the iPhone 6 Plus (iOS 8) you now need a third image MyIcon@3x.png that is 96 x 96 see [Image resolution for new iPhone 6 and 6+, @3x support added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781422/image-resolution-for-new-iphone-6-and-6-3x-support-added) for lots of good details.

Comment: This clears up my confusion about whether the dpi matters, but what can I do to make my 32x32 icon look sharper? I export it from Illustrator and it looks fine when I open it up, but when it's applied as the icon's image it gets pixelated.

Comment: you need to export a 64 x 64 icon from Illustrator too. You can't up scale from 32 too much detail is lost from the original.

Comment: I made it 64x64 then scaled it down for the 32x32.