# UIImageView sizes for x1, x2 and x3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview

In Xcode 8, If I am using the iPhone 7's storyboard size of 414x736 and I have a UIImageView of 100x100. Because the iPhone 7 is x2, do I need to provide an image of 50x50 for x1 and 150x150 for x3? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't need to. You can but you don't need to. `1x` are rather rare today.

Comment: @Sulthan Actually, Apple requires 1x images for iPad support. Our app was rejected some time ago for not providing them. Even if the app is iPhone only, it still runs in compatibility mode on iPads.

Comment: @LeoNatan Do you mean icons or all images?

Comment: Images, not icons.

Comment: @LeoNatan Very strange, that never happened to me!

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092046/for-an-iphone-only-ios-7-app-can-we-include-only-3x-images/26092471#26092471

Comment: When you use asset catalogs, it automatically creates missing slices from the images it has. So if only 3x is provided, it creates 1x and 2x variants inside the .car archive.

Comment: I recommend to use [vector graphics](http://www.programmingcrew.in/2016/09/vector-graphics-in-ios.html). By using this, you don't need to mess with 1x,2x,3x,4x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your imageView is 100*100 in storyboard (points), the recommended resolution for resource image would be 300*300 for @3x and 200*200 for @2x. If you provide only one of resolution, it will be upscaled/downscaled to fit the size.

So if you have only @3x you'll end up using more memory (2.25 times more) on devices with 2x scale.

If you have @2x only, you'll see upscale artefacts on iPhone 6/7 plus (image will be not that crisp)

Comment: Even though the 100x100 is on the storyboard and set to View as: iPhone 7?

Comment: In storyboard you set size in points. Size in pixels is doubled or tripled depending on the device.