# Do iOS 8 apps that use run in scaled mode use @3x images?

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

If I have an iOS 8 iPhone app built with Xcode 6 that doesn't provide launch images for the iPhone 6/6+ but I provide @3x images, will the iPhone 6+ still use those assets when displaying the app in scaled mode?

For example, I have `someImage.png`, `someImage@2x.png`, and `someImage@3x.png` and load the images like this:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"someImage" ofType:@"png"]];
```

I don't have an iPhone 6+ device to test this on and the iOS 8 simulator ends up using @3x images for all devices for some strange reason, as others have pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25781501/645314).

Comment: No, scaled apps think they are running on 4" devices so they use @2x images.

Comment: @rmaddy Well, dang.  If you reply to the question I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: I have to admit I wrote that comment in haste. But honestly I'm not 100% sure. I don't have a 6+, just an iPhone 6 so I can't actually verify my comment. It just seems unlikely that @3x images would be used when scaling a 3.5" or 4" app (which is what you have when you don't support the native size).

Comment: I see. Ok then, hopefully someone can definitively respond verifying that @3x images are or aren't used on the 6+ when automatic scaling is used for an app.

Comment: I have an app with no @3x images. On the iPhone 6 Plus, both simulator and device load @2x images with `imageNamed:`; sadly, normal resolution images are loaded with `imageWithContentsOfFile:`. In both cases, if @3x images are provided, they are loaded, the app being scaled or not.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone 6+ simulator in the current version of Xcode (6.3.2), does use the @3x versions of images when running in scaled mode,  with the other simulators using @2x and @1x images only.

This guide from the developers of PaintCode: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions 
also suggests that the iPhone 6+ will use @3x images before scaling.

Although I haven't got an iPhone 6+ to test that it's the same behaviour on an actual device.