# UITabbar in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uitabbar, xcode6.1

I have `UITabbarController` with 4 tabs in iPhone 4, 4s, 5, 5S it is woking fine with tabbar item image

[image]

But in iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus is looking wired.
Is it need to put different images for both iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus ?
How can I set this images.

**in iphone 6**

[image]

And, **iPhone 6 Plus**

[image]

Comment: So have you got  Solution of this question ? Please share.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same issue. The problem here is not only the different resolution, but the fact that the size of the bounds is actually wider for iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus. By running the simulator on all different phone types I found the following:

```
Tab bar Bounds
iPhone 6 plus:  414 x 49
iPhone 6:       375 x 49
iPhone 5:       320 x 49
iPhone 4        320 x 49
```

This means that you must use different background images for iphone 6 and 6 plus.
I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to do this, but it fixed it for me:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *) self.parentViewController;
UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;

if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height > 700) {
    tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-selected6Plus"];
} else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height > 600) {
    tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-selected6"];
} else {
    tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-selected"];
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This solved my problem after hours of searching!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make new size for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus.

Indeed they have new resolution: iPhone 6 (1334-by-750-pixel) and the iPhone 6 Plus (1920-by-1080-pixel).

Moreover if you are using auto-Layout you need to update your constraints.

Comment: you mean I need to add separate storyboard for iPhone 6 ?

Comment: Not necessary, you should check this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781422/image-resolution-for-new-iphone-6-and-6-3x-support-added

It explain how to implement images size on iPhone 6/ 6Plus