# TabBar in iPhone 6 and 6 plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, uitabbarcontroller

I created a TabBar for all iphone
but in iphone 5 showing properly but in iphone 6 not showing properly
image iPhone 6 showing like that i want proper spacing between tabbaritem and left and right

[image]

in Iphone 5 showing properly

[image]

I am using this code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBar;

[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"footer_bg"]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

self.delegate=self;

self.imgTab1= getImgViewForTab(CGRectMake(0, 6, 80, 39), @"listings_active.png");
self.imgTab1.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.imgTab1.autoresizingMask = LEFT_MARGIN & TOP_MARGIN & BOTTOM_MARGIN & F_WIDTH & F_HEIGHT;
[tabBar addSubview:self.imgTab1];

self.imgTab2= getImgViewForTab(CGRectMake(80, 6, 80, 39), @"bids.png");
self.imgTab2.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.imgTab2.autoresizingMask = TOP_MARGIN & BOTTOM_MARGIN & F_WIDTH & F_HEIGHT;
[tabBar addSubview:self.imgTab2];

self.imgTab3= getImgViewForTab(CGRectMake(160, 6, 80, 39), @"reservations.png");
self.imgTab3.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.imgTab3.autoresizingMask = TOP_MARGIN & BOTTOM_MARGIN & F_WIDTH & F_HEIGHT;
[tabBar addSubview:self.imgTab3];

self.imgTab4= getImgViewForTab(CGRectMake(240, 6, 80, 39), @"settings.png");
self.imgTab4.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.imgTab4.autoresizingMask = RIGHT_MARGIN & TOP_MARGIN & BOTTOM_MARGIN & F_WIDTH & F_HEIGHT;
[tabBar addSubview:self.imgTab4];

[self setSelectedTabImage:tabbarindexG];
}
```

Comment: Place code for getImgViewForTab method. Something wrong seems in that method. It seems like, you are hard coding image placements in tabbar.

Comment: inline static UIImageView *getImgViewForTab(CGRect frame, NSString *imgName)

{

    UIImageView *imgtab = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    [imgtab setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgName]];

    return imgtab;

}

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730544/uitabbar-in-xcode-6

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me as a wrong approach to assign image to tabbar item. Please refer this code;

You have to specify the images for every tab item. The following code is working for me

```
    if ([[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] respondsToSelector:@selector(setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage:)]) {

      [[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"simg1.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"]];
      [[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"simg2.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"]];

      // Do the same if there are more tabs

    }
```

Or use default `setImage` and `setSelectedImage` accessor methods:

```
// both at once
[initWithTitle:image:selectedImage:][1]

// only setImage   
 [[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"tab_1_image"]];

// only setSelectedImage
 [[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setSelectedImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"tab_1_selected_image"]];
```

iOS API will automatically adjust frame and placement for image, there is no need to assign frame for image.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: woking perfect and add my image name but not showing my images

Comment: Check your tabbar icon size is as per Apple recommendation or not. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1