# Can i use images.xcassets at 3x only?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm working on Universal Game App with Swift and SpriteKit. I'm using images.xcassets for background and any images in my project.

And I have some question.

Can I add image at 3x only (2208px X 1536px) becuase images.xcassets automatically resize image to 2x and 1x really ? But I want to know between **Add image with all size 1x,2x,3x** and **Add image at 3x only** on performance or any problems.

some case
iPhone 6 use 2x (images.xcassets automatically resize from 3x) slower than use actually 2x

This is my artwork resolution
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fDRl.png

I'm sorry for my bad English.
Thank you

Comment: take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781422/image-resolution-for-new-iphone-6-and-6-3x-support-added

Comment: now that my issue is resolved. Thank you

Comment: Share your final solution, please.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few tools out there helping out with generating asset catalogs. Google seems to favour this one:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/asset-catalog-creator-app/id809625456?mt=12

If you don´t like scaling resources, it is also possible to add vector assets using PDF. They will be rendered during build time:

http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/