# iPhone 5, iPhone 6 image sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Now that there are many different screen sizes, what images should I supply to get optimal results. E.g. from my understanding, both the iPhone 5 and 6 use @2x images. Does that mean that images are scaled up for the iPhone 6? Or are the images scaled down for the iPhone 5. What images should I supply. I can't seem to do it properly with Images.xcassets in Xcode 6.

Answer (score 0):

Our UI Designer used to create Vector Images with iPhone 5 resolution means 1136*640 ,they create 1334*750 iPhone 6 resolution images & down scale it to iPhone 5 resolution .
So we used to add iPhone 5 images only in @2x , then Xcode scales @2x images on iPhone 6 so it will not look bad as designer has created iPhone 6 resolution supported image & down scaled to iPhone 5 .

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 6 plus uses @3x, iPhone 5 @2x, so you need to be supplying at least @3x images if your supporting iPhone 6 plus.  Images will be scaled down if you just provide @3x, on older devices this uses device resources/processing power so supplying @1x @2x for older devices (if your supporting them) will enhance user experience

More information on this subject can be found here:  [Image resolution for new iPhone 6 and 6+, @3x support added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781422/image-resolution-for-new-iphone-6-and-6-3x-support-added)

Comment: i want to use edge-to-edge background images, and they don't seem to scale up or down even if iPHone 6+ images into 3x, iPhone 6 images to Retina 4 2x, iPhone 4 images to 2x.

Comment: On Simulator? Device? Both?

Comment: i'm running it on the simulator

Comment: Try on Device with @3x assets, clean project and derived data