# iPhone5 and iPhone 6 images suffix?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

We are trying to make an app for all devices ,designing it on code only.
I could see that the suffix are :

```
@2x~ipad for ipad retina
@2x for iphone5 and iphone6
@3x for iphone6+
```

But there is something that i dont get, how is that the files for `iPhone5 and 6` have the same suffix and the same name ? these images should be in a different size, and so you cant give them the same name ?

We have created images for `iPhone6` with `@2x` and they seems great on the `iPhone6` simulator, but on `iPhone5` things dont look good and cover each other .

Cant you separate these files with a different suffix?

I have read this :
[Image resolution for new iPhone 6 and 6+, @3x support added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781422/image-resolution-for-new-iphone-6-and-6-3x-support-added)

Comment: thanks, but how can i specify the launch images to let the device detect the screen size in landscape mode ? our app is landscape mode, and i have added a default image Default-568h@2x but it didn't worked ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using layout to determine how your UI elements are laid out on the screen, and you should be using Auto Layout to make sure they look right on all devices, independent of aspect ratio.

The @2x, @3x image sizes refer to device families grouped by resolution.  iPhone 5 and 6 are in the same family, and iOS will use the @2x image for both.  The size and placement of the UI element which uses that image, however, has nothing to do with the size of the image itself.

Answer (score 3):

It is because iphone 5 and iphone 6 (not including the plus) have the same pixel density. 
So basically a 40x40 image will look the same on both screens and will take the same space. You will just have to adjust positions to cover for the extra space on the iphone 6 screen.

Answer (score 2):

Images for the iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 are the same size, and the same DPI. So they share the same suffix (@2x).  They don't need to be separated.

@3x is for the iPhone 6+ because it has a higher DPI and a larger size than the other phones.  [Please refer to the Human Interface Guidelines for Images.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1)