# Background image resolution for unified storyboards

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode6

I have a background image in a unified storyboard file for all layout.
What is the recommended image resolution, width and height for that image?

Comment: I think you need to provide separate @2 and @3 versions for best results.

Comment: Create an image set inside your asset catalog. It will have slots for the image along with @2 and @3 versions.

Comment: And what is the resolution, height and width for each of those (@2x and @3x)

Comment: Here is an answer that provides a nice table: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25783648/335858).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read about Adaptive Layouts. There is a great [tutorial here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial). 
It teaches you all you need to know, using different resolution images like @2,@3 resolutions and even making device specific changes.