# Sprite kit using an image with different resolutions

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I was wondering when I'm using sprite kit do i need to have different resolutions on the same image. (@2x) (@3x) (with out storyboard)

If so how would one go about this.

Anybody that has made an app using sprite kit did u use storyboard for sprites idk ??????

Comment: Take a look at this previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781422/image-resolution-for-new-iphone-6-and-6-3x-support-added

Comment: Thanks lol I feel so stupid I didn't know it was that easy