# How to set TabBar Image in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have used `UITabBarController` in my application.

I am really confuse about what `image size` should be there for `UITabBar`. It must support all devices. `iPhone 4s,5,5s,5c,6,6 plus`.

Sometimes it's create space between tabs. If I change `image size` then sometimes it looks blur.

I have put normal image,`@2x` and also `@3x`.

```
@3x - 312*180

@2x - 160*120

normal - 80*56
```

So as per my understanding iPhone 6 should take `@2x` image but it's not taking it. There is space between tabs in iPhone 6. So I programmatically set images for iPhone 6 and give it's size as `93*56`. Then spaces between tabs has been removed and set properly. But now what problem I am facing. Images looks blur in iPhone 6. Don't know what to do now.

Can anybody please help me out here? How can I manage images of tabs which supports all devices.
Thanks in advance!

[image]
Here is my code,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication )application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary )launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    UITabBarController *tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

    UINavigationController *navController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"]];

    UINavigationController *navController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"]];

    UINavigationController *navController3 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController3"]];

    UINavigationController *navController4 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController4"]];

    tabController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController1, navController2, navController3, navController4, nil];


    [[[tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] tabBarItem]setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chords-active1.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chords1.png"]];

    [[[tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] tabBarItem]setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"progression-active1.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"progression1.png"]];

    [[[tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] tabBarItem]setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"practice-selected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"practice.png"]];

    [[[tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3] tabBarItem]setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-active1.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings1.png"]];

    self.window.rootViewController = tabController;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This link helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781422/image-resolution-for-new-iphone-6-and-6-3x-support-added?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this [IconMatrix Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html) provided by Apple. You will get everything..

Comment: I followed guide. But it's not working. Image becomes too small.

Comment: Also have you used custom tab bar controller?'

Comment: Looks like you would like to create tab bar controller based application, Right?

Comment: Then why you are not directly dragging the tab bar controller in Storyboard? Try it, Its quite easy..

Comment: I have tried that also. In that case what is happening, not a single image gets appear in tabs.

Comment: You must have missed to do certain setup in that case.. Follow this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score 1):

You should always design keeping the HIG at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1