# Xcode - iPhone 6 Plus keeps getting recognised as @2x

Tags: sprite-kit, resolution, iphone-6-plus, xcasset

I'm creating a game with SpriteKit and I have created assets for both iPhone 6 & iPhone 6 Plus sizes, but the problem is when I test in the simulator the iPhone 6 picks up whatever is in the @2x slot in the xcassets  folder. So now I'm not sure if iPhone 6+ really is @3x, and if not how can I differentiate so that each resolution gets the correct asset.

I also tried all scale modes but none of them seem to have any effect, the scene is not even scaling or something, for example my background does not fill the entire screen when running on 6+.

Edit: this question is not a duplicate of another question, because in my case the iPhone 6+ doesn't recognise @3x assets, nothing does.

Edit: Sample Project:
[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/blrid095ejeg7jx/Asset%20Test.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Did you add a LaunchScreen or the appropriate iPhone 6+ launch images?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image resolution for new iPhone 6 and 6+, @3x support added?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781422/image-resolution-for-new-iphone-6-and-6-3x-support-added)

Comment: I did not use launchscreens, but how would that help ?

Comment: Simulator dont use @3x real device will use it.

Comment: Add three **different** images for `@1x`, `@2x`, `@3x` in xcassets to differentiate which image selected by your device/simulator.

Comment: (Abhi) Are you sure that I must use a real device ? But even so, why is it not scaling the @2x images ?

(WangYudong) I already have different assets, and I know which one is being used by logging the size.

Comment: So your problem is iPhone 6p will pick `@2x` rather than `@3x`? It is correct if iPhone 6 picks `@2x`. BTW, user `@` plus username to response other's comment.

Comment: iPhone 6 picks the right asset, 6+ does not even scale the @2x assets.

Comment: Can you upload a sample project which reproduce your problem? Also include your images.

Comment: Check OP for sample project.

Comment: Have you tried it on a phone yet?

Comment: Works fine on my iPhone 6, But unfortunately I don't have 6+ available to test on, But isn't that why the simulator exists ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sample project, nothing goes wrong except that the **@3x** image has the wrong size. To achieve what you want, you need to provide a image sized 1242x2208 for the reason being explained later. And that's also the size of launch screen for iPhone 6p retina screen.

In fact, the display resolution of iPhone 6p is lower than the natural **@3x** resolution, so the **@3x** will be automatically resized to approximately 87% (downsampling) of the original size. [Learn more about the process here](http://iosdesign.ivomynttinen.com/).

**The result:**

[image]

Comment: Have you noticed that 6+ also recognised the 2x ball, and not the 3x one ?

Comment: @Abdou023 The size you print in console is 180/3=60, and 3x is truly loaded. To prove that, simply changed 3x image with any other different image, e.g, the night background and see what will display in your console.

Comment: I thought 60 is 120/2 Which the size of 2x, ok so now the right resolution for the ball for 3x should be 270 ?  270/3 = 90. and so on for all the 3x assets  ?

Comment: @Abdou023 60 for 1x, 120 for 2x and 180 for 3x.

Comment: You lost me again, because that's what they already are, 180/3 = 60, also 120 / 2 = 60, so the assets will have the same size on both 6 & 6+ which is the case right now, so why use 3x at all, if the size will reman the same ?

Comment: @Abdou023 The reason for using 3x is to make sprite looks almost same on different device screens. Add a 120x120 blue ball to the 3x image to see the difference.

Comment: I see, thank you very much for your efforts. :)
Bounty in 3 hours!